# Можно ли любой указатель рассматривать как массив из 1 элемента?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели, language-lawyer

Представим, что у нас есть нечто, например

```
char ch;
```

Мы берём адрес:

```
char *p = &ch;
```

Итак, у нас есть указатель на `char`. Мы точно знаем, что он валидный. Но можем ли мы рассматривать его как указатель на массив из одного элемента? Вроде бы логично, что да, но всплывает интересный момент:

> If the expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P.

Если мы говорим, что этот указатель можно рассматривать как указатель на массив длины 1, то этот кусок стандарта означает, что мы имеем право рассчитывать на то, что

```
assert(p < p + 1);
```

Что по сути означает, что *любой валидный указатель можно увеличить на 1 и получить число больше предыдущего (без переполнения).* Гарантирует ли это стандарт?

Для char есть есть 2 интересных адреса 0x7FFFFFFF и 0xFFFFFFFF - первый из них переполнится если 4-байтовый (для 8-байтных есть аналогичные числа - суть не меняется) указатель представлен знаковым типом, а второй - если беззнаковым. Я бы ожидал, что указатели беззнаковые, а `-1` - зарезервированный адрес, который не используется, но в стандарте скорее всего про это ничего нет. Но если подумать, для других типов данных инкремент увеличивает указатель на размер типа, а не на 1, так что там будут адреса чуть меньше. Но всё равно данные должны будут затрагивать один из этих адресов.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CNV6bQ8y

Comment: @vp_arth, на ideone [выводится `H`](https://ideone.com/p9cMa0). Или [`i`, если сменить переменную](https://ideone.com/s3tsNg) Эта программа намёк на то, что в стеке char'ы выравниваются не по 1? Но я могу его из какой-то структуры достать или ещё откуда-то. Ну и в любом случае, это ж просто пример, а не стандарт. И подозреваю, что в нём куда больше UB, чем кажется, поскольку компилятор должен бы догадаться всё заинлайнить.

Comment: Не, это UB, у меня gcc вывел Hi. Перенёс в статику, теперь более стабильно) https://godbolt.org/z/a85P6G Это к тому, что указатель на чар - это и есть массив до следующего `\0`

Comment: @vp_arth, это всё равно UB. Но просто 3 переменные лежат подряд, а cout собирает из них строку. Но мой вопрос не о разыменовании, а об инкременте и сравнении.

Comment: По поводу инкремента, цитата лишь о том, что если указатель вылез из массива на 1(Q+1), то это defined behavior и его можно сравнивать

Comment: Вопрос не по сути - потому что если брать не один элемент, а массив, заканчивающийся в 0xFFFFFFFF, то проблема будет той же. Так что рассматривать ли одну переменную как массив из одного элемента или нет - вопрос о Q+1>P остается открытым.

Comment: Вам надо шашечки или ехать? :) Менеджер памяти такого, думаю, просто не допустит...

Comment: Хм, дубликат?: [Безопасное сравнение указателей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/735995).

Comment: При арифметике указателей, одиночный элемент считается массивом из одного элемента. Ищите в стандарте по выражениям "past the end", "past the last". Что касается адреса `0xFFFFFFFF`, то это может быть только адресом за концом объекта или массива. Объект по такому адресу не расположить, а значит и указатель с этим адресом не может быть валидным за исключением случаев, когда это указатель сразу за конец объекта.

Comment: @Croessmah, "Что касается адреса `0xFFFFFFFF`, то это может быть только адресом за концом объекта или массива". Где можно почитать подробнее как конкретно реализуется выполнение этого ограничения. ОС не позволяет разместить объект по такому адресу, или в `malloc` вставлена какя-нибудь проверка. Как это работает на практике.

Comment: @Mikhailo, но для массива гарантируется это утверждение, значит массив не может заканчиваться по такому указателю.

Comment: @Qwertiy, [basic.compound/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3): "... For purposes of **pointer arithmetic**  and **comparison**, a pointer past the end of the last element of an array `x` of `n` elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical array element `n` of `x` and **an object of type `T` that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one element of type `T`**. ...".

Comment: @wololo, ответы - в ответы. Кстати, это для плюсов, нужен ещё аналогичный кусок для си.

Comment: @wololo, люди программируют и без ОС (или кто-то сам пишет ОС). Так что проблема актуальна

Comment: @avp, вполне может быть, что вся последняя страница зарезервирована так же, как и вся первая. Ну или просто один байт в список свободных адресов изначально не включили, как и нолик.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это вы о какой ОС? А если о физических адресах, то о каком железе? Кстати, железо часто сделано так, что просто обрезает старшие адреса. И тогда 0xA00F0100, 0xA0050100 и 0xA0000100 это один и тот же адрес

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++

[basic.compound/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3):

> For purposes of pointer arithmetic ([expr.add]) and comparison ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), a pointer past the end of the last element of an array `x` of `n` elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical array element `n` of `x` and **an object of type `T` that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one element of type `T`**.
>
> Для целей арифметики указателей ([expr.add]) и сравнений ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), указатель на элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним элементом массива `x` из `n` элементов, считается эквивалентным указателю на гипотетический элемент `n` массива `x`. **Также объект типа `T`, не являющийся элементом массива, считается принадлежащим массиву из одного элемента типа `T`.**

В [Expressions / Compound expressions / Unary expressions / Unary operators / 3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3) приведён пример:

```
int a;
int* p1 = &a;
int* p2 = p1 + 1;   // defined behavior
bool b = p2 > p1;   // defined behavior, with value true
```

---

В C используется аналогичный подход.

6.5.6 Additive operators / 7:

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.
>
> Для целей данных операторов (*Additive operators*), указатель на объект, не являющийся элементом массива, ведёт себя также как указатель на первый элемент массива единичной длины, с типом объекта в качестве типа элемента массива.

6.5.6 Additive operators / 8:

> ... if the expression `P` points to the last element of an array object, the expression `(P)+1` points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression `Q` points one past the last element of an array object, the expression `(Q)-1` points to the last element of the array object.
>
> ... если выражение `P` указывает на последний элемента массива, то выражение `(P)+1` указывает на элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним элементом массива. Если выражение `Q` указывает на элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним элементом массива, то выражение `(Q)-1` указывает на последний элемент массива.

6.5.8 Relational operators / 4:

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.
>
> Для целей данных операторвов (*Relational operators*), указатель на объект, не являющийся элементом массива, ведёт себя также как указатель на первый элемент массива единичной длины, с типом объекта в качестве типа элемента массива.

Answer (score 0):

Дам пару отрывков [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768659/c-safe-pointers-range)

> **Standard (first)**
>
> The Standard only guarantees that 0 is a sentinel value as far as
> pointers go. The underlying memory representation is no way
> guaranteed; it's implementation defined.
>
> Using a pointer set to that sentinel value for anything else than
> reading the pointer state or writing a new state (which includes
> dereferencing or pointer arithmetic) is undefined behavior.

Другой ответ

> The C++ standard doesn't "reserve" any pointer addresses other than
> zero (null). So it is not safe to use 1 or any other value as a
> "magic" pointer value. Of course, in practice, some implementations of
> c++ probably do not every use certain values. But you don't get any
> guarantees from the language definition.

Если вкраце то стандарт не ограничивает вас инкрементирование вашего указателя, но и не гарантирует вам ничего, зависимостей не мало конкретная OS, конкретная реализация компилятора все это варьируется.

A ваш пример со сравнением проверяется просто. Задайте значение для p на границе и инкрементируйте не думаю что это запрещено. Другое дело получите ли вы такое значение p в реальности.